# What is the purpose of using UIViewController IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, iboutlet

I am in the learning phase of iOS programming. I am trying to add a NIB (called B) in another NIB (called A). To do so, I have added a View Controller in A which uses the B NIB (using NIB Name). In addition, in the A's ViewController, I have created an IBOutlet to store B's ViewController. Finally, in A I have connected the IBOutlet to the ViewController referring to B.

Now, I expect that when I run the project, I would see that B is loaded whenever A is loaded, but that is not the case. To achieve this, I have to initialize B pragmatically using initWithNibName in A's viewDidLoad method, and set it to the IBOutlet. But this part is something that is not dependent of using both IBOutlet in A and adding a ViewController to A that refers to B. In other words, if I had simply initialized B in A's viewDidLoad without creating an IBOutlet in A and without creating a View Controller object in A, that would have worked just as well.

So my question is, what is the purpose of using IBOutlet for adding custom View Controller NIBs?

Comment: IBOutlet is simply a mark for interfacebuilder, also remember views and their associated nibs are lazy loaded in cocoa touch

Comment: If you are still learning the basics, do not try to embed a viewcontroller in another viewcontroller. Learn basics first. Get a good starters tutorial and read the developers guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you have outlet to VC B in VC A, that does not mean view of VC B will be loaded automatically. If you check VC B outlet in VC A viewDidLoad, you'll see there is address to VC B, therefore NIB is loaded. To load its view, you have to access VCB.view and call appropriate methods in VCB like this:

```
[self.bViewController setFrame:[self frame]];
    [self.bViewController viewDidLoad];
[self.bViewController viewWillAppear:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.bViewController.view];
[self.bViewController viewDidAppear:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do all that, and adding another viewcontroller view in currently displayed view controller view hierarchy causes problems like interface rotation or touch events do not delivered properly.

You can use `uiviewcontroller's presentViewController:animated:completion:` method to load `bViewController's view hierarchy` and all the methods like `viewDidAppear, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear` will be called automatically you do not need to call them manually.

You will find this article [Abusing UIViewControllers](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/) useful.